# Python 3: remove attributes from class before instancing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm working with Python3, and I have a really heavy class with many functions as attributes:

```
Class A (object):

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def method1(self):
        ...

    def method2(self):
        ...


        ...

    def methodN(self):
        ...
```

I would like to create an instance of class A that only has `method1`, for example. How could I do this?

Using inheritance, though it might be the most technically correct way, is not an option in my case - I can't modify the codebase so much.

I thought about decorating the class and deleting its attributes before `__init__` is called, but I'm not even sure where to start tackling this. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @kaya3 I want to do this because the original class is very heavy with such a big number of functions inside it. It was working fine the way it was being used, but a new use case has arisen where we need to call it from another endpoint, just to use one or two of its methods (these methods will be different each time and specified as parameters).

Comment: Are you under the impression that the methods are copied to the instance when the instance is created? That's not the case.

Comment: Do you mean that an instance of `class A` with a hundred methods will take up as much memory as an instance of `class B` with just one method (being all the methods the same)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Both just hold a reference to their `__class__` attribute, and the methods are looked up on that. You can test with `sys.getsizeof`.

Comment: I'll add that this is a code smell - you might not want to inherit from that enormous base class. Instead, you can start to think about extracting a simpler common class and having both of the functional types inherit from _that_.

Comment: @kaya3 I just checked and you are absolutely right. Thank you for opening my eyes!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `__getattribute__` method of the class to disallow access to those attributes (via normal `instance.attribute` access)

```
class A (object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def method1(self):
        ...
    def method2(self):
        ...
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if object.__getattribute__(self, 'x'):
            if name == 'method2':
                raise AttributeError("Cannot access method2 is self.x is True")
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

>>> a = A(False)
>>> a.method1
<bound method A.method1 of <__main__.A object at 0x000001E25992F248>>
>>> a.method2
<bound method A.method2 of <__main__.A object at 0x000001E25992F248>>
>>> b = A(True)
>>> b.method1
<bound method A.method1 of <__main__.A object at 0x000001E25992F2C8>>
>>> b.method2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in __getattribute__
AttributeError: Cannot access method2 is self.x is True
```

Obviously, this gets pretty unwieldy and violates a lot of assumptions about what it means to be an instance of a class.  I can't think of a good reason to do this in real code, as you can still access the methods through `object.__getattribute__(b, 'method2')`